# Rest API to get the list of files inside the container/directory/ in AZURE storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, azure-container-service, azure-rest-api

I have a container called 'services'.Inside the Container , i have a directory called 'Test'.how we can get the list of blobs inside the directory test.I have few kept few CSVs inside the test. Need the rest api to get the list of the files.
However i am able to get the list of items inside the container easily using below Rest API
https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/services?restype=container&comp=list

i tried
https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/services/Test?restype=directory&comp=list
but it is not working.
Please help to get the coorect param value or rest API to find the list of items inside the directory

Comment: You need add a param.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/services/Test?restype=directory&comp=list&prefix=Test/
```

The doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/list-blobs#uri-parameters

Just add a param `prefix` is ok.